# sbt error importing JS libraries with scala-js 1.x.x

Tags: scala, scala.js

I am facing this issue when upgrading from scala-js 0.6.x to 1.x.x, and the issue is:-

with **scala-js 0.6.x**, I had the following **build.sbt** setting:-

```
name := "untitled2"
version := "0.1"
scalaVersion := "2.13.3"

enablePlugins(JSDependenciesPlugin)

jsDependencies += "org.webjars.npm" % "opentelemetry__context-base" % "0.8.3" / "context.js" commonJSName "Context"
jsDependencies += "org.webjars.npm" % "opentelemetry__context-base" % "0.8.3" / "NoopContextManager.js" commonJSName "NoopContextManager" dependsOn "context.js"

scalaJSModuleKind := ModuleKind.CommonJSModule
scalaJSUseMainModuleInitializer := true
```

and the main class:-

```
object Main extends App {

  println("hello js")
}
```

and the **plugins.sbt** file:-

```
addSbtPlugin("org.scala-js" % "sbt-scalajs" % "0.6.33")
```

when I run the following command **sbt clean run** I get the output as- **hello js**.

with **scala-js 1.x.x**, I had the following **build.sbt** settings: -

```
name := "untitled2"
version := "0.1"
scalaVersion := "2.13.3"

enablePlugins(JSDependenciesPlugin)

jsDependencies += "org.webjars.npm" % "opentelemetry__context-base" % "0.8.3" / "context.js" commonJSName "Context"
jsDependencies += "org.webjars.npm" % "opentelemetry__context-base" % "0.8.3" / "NoopContextManager.js" commonJSName "NoopContextManager" dependsOn "context.js"

scalaJSLinkerConfig ~= { _.withModuleKind(ModuleKind.CommonJSModule) }
scalaJSUseMainModuleInitializer := true
```

with **plugins.sbt** file as:-

```
addSbtPlugin("org.scala-js" % "sbt-scalajs" % "1.1.1")
addSbtPlugin("org.scala-js" % "sbt-jsdependencies" % "1.0.2")
```

when I try to execute the same command as **sbt clean run**, then I get the following error:-

```
[error] org.scalajs.jsenv.ExternalJSRun$NonZeroExitException: exited with code 1
[error]         at org.scalajs.jsenv.ExternalJSRun$$anon$1.run(ExternalJSRun.scala:186)
[error] stack trace is suppressed; run 'last Compile / run' for the full output
[error] (Compile / run) org.scalajs.jsenv.ExternalJSRun$NonZeroExitException: exited with code 1
[error] Total time: 3 s, completed 03-Sep-2020, 5:21:51 pm
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1083
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module './context'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp-8158890692830924760NoopContextManager.js
- D:\untitled2\[stdin]
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1080:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:923:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1140:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:75:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp-8158890692830924760NoopContextManager.js:18:19)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1251:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1272:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1100:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:962:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1140:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmp-8158890692830924760NoopContextManager.js',
    'D:\\untitled2\\[stdin]'
  ]
}
```

Can someone help me in understanding what's the issue here? And how can I solve that?